# TortoiseSVN missing file in update

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We have occasionally had a problem with TortoiseSVN (I assume it's Tortoise and not our SVN repository), where a file will be checked in to the repository (doing a repo-browser you can see the files there), and will exist for the person who committed them, but when another person does an update, those files will not be added to the working copy. If I then choose "Copy to working copy..." from the repo-browser, and attempt a commit, the files are treated as new for me and my client tries to add them, giving an error. Updating also results in some error (I don't know how to reproduce this so I don't know what specifically would cause this and I don't remember the exact errors). I have to then delete the files from the repository, and commit the files as new. After this, everything works fine and the original person has no problems with their files.

The repository is accessed via the svn:// protocol, to a server running version 1.4.6. It is hosted on a Windows Server 2003 machine running as a Windows service.

The repository is laid out as follows:

```
[repository]/Code/[projects]
[repository]/Code/[Website]/*some page in here*
[repository]/Data/[misc data files]
[repository]/References/[dlls/references]
```

This almost exclusively happens with .aspx/.aspx.cs/.aspx.designer.cs, and usually all 3 at a time. As if an entire "page" won't be added to my folder. This has happened with Visual Studio open and running the Solution, and also with no Visual Studio open either.

Has anyone seen this before, and do you know the cause/solution?

Comment: Could you post the version of TortoiseSVN and how your SVN is hosted (http://, svn://, local, etc.) and by what means (Apache, IIS, VisualSVN, etc.) including any other version numbers.

Comment: Also try recreating the working directories (just make an additional one) to see if something went wrong when you checked out the first time.

Comment: As a first step upgrade to the latest version of TSVN (1.6.3 right now). I beliebe there was a related bug in 1.6.x which was fixed in version 1.6.2.

Comment: We're experiencing this same issue with TortoiseSVN 1.7 client connected to a Subversion 1.6 repository. Is there a similiar fix out there somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also have had the described problem sometimes. Just at the moment, it happened again. Same situation: There were multiple files changed/added/deleted/moved at the SVN server from an SVN client A and SVN client B updated its working copy (using Tortoise SVN). After the update, some of the files which were added from A are not present in the working copy of B, but the repository browser shows them at the correct location at the SVN server.
Updating again with Tortoise always claims that everything is at the current revision.
Also an "svn up" in the folder where the files are missing says that everything is at the current revision.

I'm using

Tortoise SVN 1.6.6, Build 17493 - 64 Bit

Visual SVN 1.7 (SVN integration into Visual Studio 2008)

Edit:
It seems to be a known problem, here is the solution: http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2379518

Comment: For anyone else : Here's the direct solution : 
for each of the
troublesome working copies use "Update to revision" and set the
working copy depth to "Fully Recursive".

Answer (score 3):

you can test whether it is tortoise or svn by using the command line tools. type 'svn up' in the WC root directory.

As you say you're on 1.4.6, you're not having a problem with sparse directories. Do have ignored files in your client settings? Are you sure your WC is pointing at the correct URL in the repository and hasn't been switched to a different branch? (you can see this in the folder's properties - there's a subversion tab)

If you do 'svn status' in your WC you should see the list of changed files in the server's directory.

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced the same problem with SVN 1.6.2 and 1.6.3 (command-line, Tortoise and Subclipse). so it seems that problem is related to SVN itself.
Following workaround exists - try to checkout to the same directory - it just addes missing files.

Answer (score 1):

I have also experienced this bug with Tortoise SVN with at least 1.6.2 to what I'm currently using 1.6.5.
"Get latest" will not get the files from the repository.  I've had to delete the affected directory and get latest on the parent directory to re-create the directory and it's contents.

gbjbaanb, this is definitely not a case of ignored files or switched branches.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't quite able to solve this issue using the instructions in Daniel's link, but I agree it seems to be a core issue with most SVN implementations in Windows, at the very least.

In order to fix my missing folder issue, my steps were:

1. "Update to revision", selecting a commit number before any file in the folder was modified, added, or deleted, and make sure you choose "Fully recursive".  (This will cause some strange error in Tortoise.  That's expected!)
2. Execute a Cleanup.
3. Update the folder again and you should get the whole folder!

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous answers above didn't work for me.  I had the same problem: A folder that I was working on had a few uncommitted objects in it.  That folder was updated with many objects by another user.  I could see that user's objects in the repository but everytime I did an update I would never get that user's objects.

The fix that worked is to use TortoiseSVN [Revert](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.svn.c.revert.html) on the folder.